# How to get value from many select boxes inside div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've created quite interesting html contraption like this

```
<div class="alert alert-info" id="1">
    <select name="first" id="sel-1-1">
         <option value="1">One</option>
         <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    <select name="second" id="sel-2-1">
         <option value="1">One</option>
         <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now my question is, how to push values of all selected options in div, inside array **using jquery**? Have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` to create an array of the selected values:

```
var selectedValueArray = $('.alert select').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3Wy7p/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var new_item = '<option value="3">Three</option>';
$('.alert select').append(new_item);
```